# NullPointerException with ImageButtons Array

Tags: android, arrays, layout, nullpointerexception, imagebutton

I declared an `ImageButton` array manually and then add some `ImageButtons` manually to it, and after assigning these `ImageButtons` to the XML layout, I tried to iterate through that array using a for loop, but I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when iterating through that array(the Exception comes with the first Iterate it's not even manage the iteration once), that's my code:

```
public ImageButton Antenna, AV, Components, VGA, HDMI, Switch;
public ImageButton[] upControllingButtons = {Antenna, AV, Components, VGA, HDMI, Switch};
        Antenna = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.antenna);
            // then the other six ImageButtons

        // setting the onClick for the Up_Controlling butoons
        for(int k=0; k < upControllingButtons.length ; k++ ){
            upControllingButtons[k].setTag("tag"); // i got the Exception here
        }
```

and the `ImageButton` in the XML:

```
                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/antenna"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                android:background="@drawable/remote_living_buttons"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                                android:src="@drawable/remote_living_antena"
                                android:tag="released" />
                                <!.. then the other six ..!>
```

and that is the `LogCat` result:

```
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.solaceap/com.example.solaceap.RemoteTV}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at com.example.solaceap.RemoteTV.get_available_devices(RemoteTV.java:221)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at com.example.solaceap.RemoteTV.onCreate(RemoteTV.java:81)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-23 11:43:11.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
```

Comment: @Raghunandan If you read the code properly (and his comment) he uses `findViewById` on all 6, so does initialise them all. Its not clear though due to him having hid the code.

Comment: Did you set the contentView for your Activity??

Comment: post the full code. its not clear what you are doing

Comment: @Namecan'tbedisplayed sure i did

Comment: Check the @NarendraSoni answer,that might be the problem:)

Comment: @Namecan'tbedisplayed I'm trying that right now, just waiting the creepy emulator to run

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try inflating first then add to the array like:

```
 Antenna = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.antenna);
 ...
 ...
 public ImageButton[] upControllingButtons = {Antenna, AV, Components, VGA, HDMI, Switch};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ImageButton[] upControllingButtons = new ImageButton[7];
Antenna = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.antenna);
//Then Do your work
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Your approch is wrong do not use separate line for each ImageButton to initialize you can use loop instead.

try this.

You have to give the ids of your ImageButton by numbers. like

```
<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/button2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/button3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

ArrayList<ImageButton> upControllingButtons = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    upControllingButtons .add(getImageButton(i));
}


private ImageButton getImageButton(int i)
{
    int id=0;

     try {
         id = R.id.class.getField("button" + i).getInt(0);
        }
     catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (SecurityException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(id);
             return imageButton
}
```